Alert user before leaving to notification activity when app is in foreground
I am using FCM for push notifications on Android and everything is working fine, I just have this requirement that I need to implement but I am not sure if this is possible.
So, when the app is in foreground (user is using the app) and a push notification pops up and the user clicks on it, the notification will take him to some TARGET SCREEN,
What I want is when the user clicks the notification, is it possible to show an Alert dialog (no matter what is the current screen) warning the user that he is leaving the current screen (with go/decline buttons) ?
PS: I am currently using my SplashActivity (which is my launching activity) for the pending intent
val intent = Intent(this, SplachActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra(ENTITY_ID, entityId?.toInt())
                    putExtra(ENTITY_TYPE, entityType)
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                }

                val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
                    addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
                    getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                    )
                }

                val bitmap: Bitmap? = fetchBitmapFromUrl(notificationImageUrl, this)

                val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_NEW_CONTENT)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yaraBlue))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(description)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_yara)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setStyle(
                        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(bitmap)
                            .bigLargeIcon(null)
                    )
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build()


Use a custom broadcast receiver or handle it in your main activity to show the AlertDialog.
Broadcast receiver
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val entityId = intent.getIntExtra(ENTITY_ID, -1)
        val entityType = intent.getStringExtra(ENTITY_TYPE)

        // Launch an activity to show the dialog
        val dialogIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(ENTITY_ID, entityId)
            putExtra(ENTITY_TYPE, entityType)
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        context.startActivity(dialogIntent)
    }
}

Show dialog in mainactivity
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    // Check if this activity was launched from a notification
    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(ENTITY_ID)) {
        val entityId = intent.getIntExtra(ENTITY_ID, -1)
        val entityType = intent.getStringExtra(ENTITY_TYPE)

        // Show the AlertDialog
        showLeaveScreenDialog(entityId, entityType)
    }
}

private fun showLeaveScreenDialog(entityId: Int, entityType: String?) {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Leaving Current Screen")
    builder.setMessage("You are about to leave the current screen. Do you want to proceed?")
    
    builder.setPositiveButton("Go") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
        // Navigate to the target screen here
        navigateToTargetScreen(entityId, entityType)
    }

    builder.setNegativeButton("Decline") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    builder.show()
}

private fun navigateToTargetScreen(entityId: Int, entityType: String?) {
    // Implement navigation to your target screen here
}

Modify your PendingIntent
val intent = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
    putExtra(ENTITY_ID, entityId?.toInt())
    putExtra(ENTITY_TYPE, entityType)
}

val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this,
    0,
    intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)

Try this
